# Loading indicator on Http requests

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, typescript1.8

The root of my problem is displaying a loading indicator on http requests, and I want to do it at the service level without having to write code for each component. What I did was implement an http wrapper that basically does this:

```
getMyHttpObservable(...) {
    setLoadingIndicator(true);
    const myHttpObservable = 
        createRequestObservable().finally(()=> {
            console.log('http done');
            setLoadingIndicator(false);
        });
    return myHttpObservable;
}
```

I have a sequence of observables which I chain using `Observable.concat` as follows:

```
const t1 = Observable.timer(5000).finally(()=>console.log('t1 done'));
const t2 = getMyHttpObservable(...);
const agg = Observable.concat(t1,t2);
```

I am using an event based cancellation technique using `Observable.takeUntil` as follows:

```
const ev = new EventEmitter<any>();
const cancellableAgg = agg.takeUntil(ev.asObservable());
```

Now the problem is when I cancel the aggregate observable during the first timer period I do not get the finally call of the 2nd observable - the http request. Example:

```
const cancel = Observable.timer(500).finally(()=>ev.emit());
cancellableAgg.subscribe();
cancel.subscribe();
```

When the above runs, I get this output:

```
t1 done
```

And I need to get `http done` as well, so that the loading indicator is cleared. How can I achieve that?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I failed to realize that the `concat` operator only subscribes to observables down the line, when their predecessors have completed. What I need is to activate my loading indicator only when the http observable has actually been subscribed to.

I modified my wrapper function as follows:

```
getMyHttpObservable(...) {
    const myHttpObservable = createRequestObservable(...);
    const subscriptionAware = new Observable(subscriber => {
        setLoadingIndicator(true);
        myHttpObservable.subscribe(
            nextEv => subscriber.next(nextEv),
            errEv => subscriber.error(errEv),
            () => subscriber.complete())
        .add(()=>setLoadingIndicator(false));
    };
    return subscriptionAware;
}
```

So basically, I'm creating an `Observable` which transparently wraps another `Observable`, but also performs some additional actions when it's actually subscribed to - activate the loading indicator.

However, now I've lost the ability to cancel XHR requests in flight, since the constructor of `Observable` doesn't allow me to pass a handler for cancellation, so the inner subscription will never get cancelled.

Any ideas as to how to achieve that?

Comment: I would suggest a different approach, which is to define a **decorator** to apply to methods where you want to put up a spinner. Putting the spinner at the http level is not flexible enough, and confuses networking logic with UI IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to find a solution using the built in `defer` operator which waits for a subscription and returns a fresh observable:

```
getMyHttpObservable(...) {
    const myHttpObservable = createRequestObservable(...);
    return Observable.defer(() => {
        setLoadingIndicator(true);
        return myHttpObservable.finally(() => setLoadingIndicator(false));
    });
}
```

Elegant and short.