# UI blocker in Angular2 application

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript1.8

I am developing an application which interacts to database multiple times. Every time it takes time to get response from server. Between this request and response I want to block my UI interaction and show some loading circle or some text width some dark background. How this can be achieved?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please post the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish and what you have tried and where you failed. Basically you enable the animation when you make the request and cancel it when you receive the response.

Comment: Looking something like this and don't know where to start:

http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#demos

Comment: I would say this question is to broad for SO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading indicator on Http requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39190672/loading-indicator-on-http-requests)